# How to install Jio Meet on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: wine

## Background

[Jio Meet](https://jiomeetpro.jio.com/home) is a video chat app. It does not have an installer for Ubuntu. I tried to install it using wine using the command

`wine JioMeetInstaller.exe`. I got the following error `0009:err:mscoree:load_mono Could not load Mono into this process`

## Question

How to install this particular app? Are there any non-wine solutions? If wine is the only way, then how to address the mono related error.

## Other similar questions

[This](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=172531) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31259589/mono-does-not-appeared-to-be-installed-error-winetricks-even-though-its-insta) question discuss the same issue.
Based on their inputs, I installed `sudo apt-get install mono-complete`
and `sudo apt-get install mono-vbnc`. However, the problem still persists.

## Additional information

Version of Wine:

```
wine --version
wine-5.0 (Ubuntu 5.0-3ubuntu1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now JioMeet is not supported by wine. JioMeet is not listed in [AppDB of wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/). Regarding other installation method, No package available for linux platform at all, So at this point (writing on date 23th July 2020) not possible to install Jio Meet in Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, as illustrated in the previous answer.

But you use the service in Chrome. Unfortunately, they don't support Firefox but Chrome Ubuntu runs it just as well as Chrome windows.